# How to display values from one vf page into another vf pge

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having a VF page where I save the values of name and email.Now I have to pass this values into another page and need to display their.

Note: I'm saving values of name,email into Account,Contact directly through trigger....I'm not having any custom object for this.

Comment: could you provide some more information?

Wouldn't it be possible to just query the object you inserted in the first place in the second page's extension?
Or are you trying to create some sort of wizard like approach?

Comment: Does your VF page has controller or (Standardcontroller and extensions)?

Comment: I'm having my VF Page in a site address(say http://example-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/exaddress) and I'm sending this site in an email.So when a user clickes on the site,details of name and email should be displayed.This is my requirement.Help!!!!! It has controller

Comment: Got it...I can use the same class for the two different pages.So that I can get name,email directly. Now my problem is how the condition here should be so that after commandbutton works values should render into another page.`  <apex:outputtext value="{!fname}"/> <apex:outputtext value="{!email}"/>`.In constructor `fname=billing.billingname; email=billing.billingemail;` Hope this was clear.(I can't use Id here)

Answer (score 4):

You might use the tutorial for making a multi-page [wizard](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm).

Or if there's not too many parameters, pass them through URL (best would be to use ApexPages.PageReference, getParameters() gives you a map, you can put values there. But if you really want, you can craft the URL string by hand).

Answer (score 1):

You could use pagereference class
I would have this code on the commandbutton of the first VF page

```
    PageReference pr = new PageReference ();
    pr = Page.VFpage; // use the name of the second VF page
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    pr.getParameters().put('Pstartdate',string.valueof(startdate1));
    pr.getParameters().put('Penddate', string.valueof(enddate1));
```

This should redirect to second VF page with the parameters in query string

and capture these on the constructor of  controller of the next VF page using

```
    startdate1=date.valueof(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Pstartdate'));
    enddate1=date.valueof(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Penddate'));
```

You should have these ready to be used in the second VF page

Comment: can you be more clear in this @Prady

Comment: @eagerinsf  updated the answer to make it more clearer. Hope this helps